# Is there a way to get Google's answers to questions in Python?

Tags: python, google-search

When searching Google and input things like "How tall is the Eiffel tower?" Google will come back with an answer directly on the page.

Is there a way in Python to enter a search term and get this answer within python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This needs to be handled programme. 
First you need to have google API key.
secondly,set up your custom search engine. Read more  http://www.google.com/cse/
third Install Google API client for python.
now you are ready to search.

Comment: Thanks, I've looked at that but worry it will only get me links and not the automated answers to questions. Do you know if it can return those too?